# How to watch for hidden gems?

Tags: discussion, support, review

In late answers review I found a helping notice as:

> This is a new user's answer to an old question. Watch for hidden gems, non-answers, and spam

I understand what non-answers and spam refers to, but what is meant by *hidden gems?* I don't want the meaning; I want to know how can we find the *hidden objects* in the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden objects"?

Comment: If I know that , why would I post a Question Here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hidden gems means something which is extremely outstanding and not many people may know about. In the present context (Late Answers Review Queue), where people come out of blue and provide an exemplary answer.

Examples of exemplary answers: https://askubuntu.com/badges/25/great-answer

Comment: A hidden gem is something that, hitherto, has gone unnoticed and is unappreciated despite having value. In the context of Ask Ubuntu answers, that, IMO, *should* translate to no or few upvotes as opposed to the upvotes the answer deserves. Why it is associated with Late Answers, I haven't a clue.

Comment: @vasa1 you got point .