# Some data lost after Stack Exchange server migration Feb. 9

Tags: support, bug, stackexchange

As some of you have noticed, the SE admins were [migrating the services to the NY data centre](http://stackstatus.net/post/42602026025/succeeding-back-to-new-york-feb-9-2013) again yesterday.

Unfortunately, some data seems to have been lost in the minutes before the site became read-only. It's at least a few minutes, but maybe more. On MSO, this has been [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166940/195914), as it was a SE-wide issue. This was [acknowlegded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166940/welcome-back-meta-goodbye-question#comment489233_166940) by the SE team and it appears that data *is* restorable and that it was [successful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/166940/3) for MSO.

In that very post on MSO I mentioned AU as well (I only had specific evidence for a Meta-AU post), but now the post is closed while none of the data here has been restored.

> On Meta AU we lost an answer to this question: [How to watch for hidden gems?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6021/how-to-watch-for-hidden-gems). There were two, the one answered by [AbrahamVanHelpsing](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/5768/abrahamvanhelpsing) is gone. – gertvdijk [23 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166940/welcome-back-meta-goodbye-question#comment489273_166940)

and

> What do you mean "closed as too localized"? Data is still lost on AU! – gertvdijk [15 mins ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166940/welcome-back-meta-goodbye-question#comment489608_166940)

With the response:

> @gertvdijk Make that a new question. – Bart [14 mins ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166940/welcome-back-meta-goodbye-question#comment489609_166940)

So, there it is. The new "question":

#### Can we please get our data back on AU and MAU?

*This example in the comments is just one example. I've heard reports of people losing reputation and upvotes as well.*