# Hidden Gems - Late Answers Review Queue

Tags: discussion

At the top of the Late Answers Review Queue is this warning.

**This is a new user's answer to an old question. Watch for hidden gems, non-answers, and spam.**

What are hidden gems?

Comment: This has already been answered here. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6021/how-to-watch-for-hidden-gems although it only appeared after I'd posted this.